# Как можно получить все найденые строки в цикле?

Tags: pcre, регулярные-выражения, c++

Здраствуйте. Я использую pcrecpp на c++ ( PCRE библиотека )
И мне нужна помощь, как можно получить все найденые строки в цикле?

К примеру паттерн:
"hello"

и текст 
"hello hello hello"

Нужно напечатать его в цикле
1 hello  
2 hello
3 hello

Псевдокод:

```
pcrecpp::RE pPattern ( "hello" );  
std::string strBase = "hello hello hello";  
// ...  
int iMatches = // Получение совпадений  
for ( int i = 1; i < iMatches; i++ )   
{  
    printf( "%d %s", i, pPattern[ i ].c_str () );  
}
```

Как я могу это сделать? Какой метод существует для этого? Если не сложно покажите пример кода.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcrecpp.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    pcrecpp::RE pPattern ( "(\\bhello\\b)" );  
    string strBase = "hello hello hello";  
    pcrecpp::StringPiece input(strBase);
    string r;
    while(pPattern.FindAndConsume(&input, &r)) {
        cout << r << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

То, что собирать надо с ключом -lpcrecpp Вы знаете.

Comment: Спасибо вам.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Заходите ещё. А вот награждение последней (и первой) имеющейся единичкой репутации было явно лишним. Вам оно нужнее (см. нижнюю границу по очкам для тех или иных действий)